# Mopub is not working with Admob any more?

Tags: mopub

I've been using Ludei to compile my app, and I am trying to integrate Mopub ads on my app.
The first time that I executed my app, an ad with Mopub welcome message was shown, and suddenly anything else was shown any more.
I don't know what is happening because when I started using Ludei, one of my concerns was to test the Mopub plugin, to make sure that I would have a viable way to monetize my app, and at that time, it worked fine, but now I can't manage to make it works anymore.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MoPub is a great way to help you monetize your applications. It is an ad mediation company which Ludei has bundled into their SDK offering for the ad serving solution part.

You would need to register at mopub.com first and associate ad networks to your mobile applications within MoPub.  Those ad networks you add to the mopub dashboard would need respective credentials which you will receive when you create ad network accounts, example over at admob.com

MoPub side:
1-Register an account at mopub.com
2-Determine the ad unit id size you wish to have
3-Add ad networks and associate them with your ad unit id
4-consult more here:  http://help.mopub.com/

AdNetwork side:
1-register and create an account on the ad network of interest
2-input that ad network credential back to your mopub account

Comment: Ok, those are the basic steps to configure an app, I've been trough it many times, and double checked every one of this before asking for help.
This probably is a bug on ludei or maybe on mopub.
That's what I trying to figure out and work around.

Comment: May you post the logs?  If you are seeing creatives come in when you click the 'Test Ad' button within MoPub dashboard then we can dilute the issue down to the integrate steps with Ludei.